# Magento 2 : Javascript Developer Certification reading material

Tags: magento2, javascript, certification

Magento just announced   **[JavaScript Certification](https://u.magento.com/magento-2-certified-professional-javascript-developer#.W6XjchThWkA)** exam for Magento2.

After reading in this page:

> https://u.magento.com/magento-2-certified-professional-javascript-developer

I have some questions about this **JavaScript Developer Certification exam.**

- Which study materials useful for preparation of Java script Certification exam?
- What is the passing score for this Java script Certification exam?
- Is there any other study materials available for this exam?
- What is the retake policy for this exam?

Answer (score 6):

Here is some question that are available on magento.

What is the passing score for this Java script Certification exam?

**Passing score: 63% or above**

What is the retake policy for this exam?

**All retakes have a 20% discount.**
[Reference](https://magento-u-support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011820892-How-much-is-the-exam-fee-and-cost-to-retake-exams-)

Which study materials useful for preparation of Java script Certification exam?

[Study guideline](https://magento-u.magento.com/magento-u/downloads/M2_Cert_Prof_JavaScript_Dev_Exam_Study_Gd.pdf?_ga=2.6270391.544070576.1537770549-477153403.1520249292)

Is there any other study materials available for this exam?

**i could not find any yet. all are related to frontend study  but not specific for javascript**

Answer (score 2):

Passing Score : Passing score is 63% as per information at https://magento-u-support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011824472-What-is-a-passing-score-for-the-certification-exams-


Study material other than the study guide provided by Magento : Swiftotter will be releasing soon, check at https://swiftotter.com/certifications/magento-2-javascript-developer-study-guide


Course offered by Magento : https://u.magento.com/javascript-development-in-magento-2#.W6oWQRMzZAY


Retake Policy :
[image: retake-policy]

[image: retake-policy]

Answer (score 0):

**Latest study guide certifications:updated [21 August 2020]**:

- **[AD0-E700]:** *Adobe Certified Expert Magento Commerce Business Practitioner*  [Details](https://spark.adobe.com/page/87jLctNB6KxM0/)
- **[AD0-E701]:** *Adobe Certified Expert-Magento Commerce Front-End Developer* [Details](https://spark.adobe.com/page/lJWBfPhvp5npA/)
- **[AD0-E702]:** *Adobe Certified Professional—Magento Commerce Developer*  [Details](https://spark.adobe.com/page/saM506xrYKi0p/)
- **[AD0-E703]:** *Adobe Certified Expert - Magento Commerce Developer* [Details](https://spark.adobe.com/page/OwpmK2JcACwhl/)
- **[AD0-E704]:** *Adobe Certified Master Magento Commerce Architect* [Details](https://spark.adobe.com/page/PTidDHsT5JgyB/)
- **[AD0-E705]:** *Adobe Certified Expert-Magento Commerce JavaScript Developer*  [Details](https://spark.adobe.com/page/ZDus3If2u1rQf/)
- **[AD0-E706]:** *Adobe Certified Expert-Magento Commerce Cloud Developer* [available since June 2018] [Details](https://spark.adobe.com/page/GrkbPktpWMkkb/)
- **[Adobe AD0-E707]** Adobe Certified Expert Magento Commerce Order Management Developer [Details](https://spark.adobe.com/page/K2Wjl6Na3BY0h/)